# How do I suppress output from PROC SURVEYFREQ?

Tags: excel, sas

I want to export my results to a multi-sheet Excel file. Since I want to keep my formatting and since I can't stand working with DDE this leaves me with no choice than using ODS. I create my data via macros, and my plan is to simply wrap all said macros inside the ODS statement while suppressing the output from everything inside each macro apart from the final printout (Since ODS would overwrite my files if I were to do this sequentially).

I have some problems suppressing the printout of PROC SURVEYFREQ:

```
proc SURVEYFREQ data= a;
tables &var /CL noprint;
WEIGHT kalvikt;
ods output OneWay=a1 noprint;
run;
```

This still produces output which could mess up my final printout:

[image]

Can I suppress this output and in that case how?

Comment: Do you want to exclude part of the HTML output or simply not output to the HTML destination at all?

Comment: I don't want to output anything at all except to the data object (a1) in the output statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply close the ODS HTML Destination like this

```
ods html close;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add ODS SELECT before the step to select the ODS output objects you want to print.  If you want no printout then use ODS SELECT NONE;

```
ods select none;
ods output OneWay=a1 ;
proc SURVEYFREQ data= a;
  tables &var /CL noprint;
  WEIGHT kalvikt;
run;
ods select all;
```